# Azure website global memory sharing/cache synchronicity

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, memory, asp.net-web-api2

How do Azure websites scale out? I'm interested in memory: is it global for all copies of websites or does each copy have its own memory?

If I scale out my websites, can my memory cache be cleared by every copy, or do I need to clear it from every website copy individually?

Comment: Each instance has its own memory.  Not sure what you mean by "clearing memory cache".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every instance is isolated and has its own memory space. If you're maintaining an in-memory cache in your websites, each website must manage its own in-memory cache. They are not shared.